# Can't use android-support libs - NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

i am trying to use the ActionBar from the support library to execute my app on a device running android 2.3

I already added `android-support-v4.jar` and `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` but id don't work.
There is no errors on the code, but if i try to run it on the device i get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:54)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:96)
            at br.mviccari.spylogger.activities.Main.onCreate(Main.java:14)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.<clinit>(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:47)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:54)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:96)
            at br.mviccari.spylogger.activities.Main.onCreate(Main.java:14)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using Intellij IDEA, i have read that for eclipse users it's just add the lib, but for Intellij i need something else, i just don't know what...
How can i solve it?

Comment: You don't add the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` in libs. Instead, you add a reference to the imported appCompat project (It's in the sdk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using IntelliJ, use [Android Studio 0.8.2](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) instead; you will have to update from 0.8 to 0.8.2 within Android Studio. The newer beta version will play nice with you from now on from update to update. You won't have to worry about updates changing everything. Google specifically stated that.

So with this IDE, you don't have to worry about the support libraries, they are baked in, and you can include them in from the `new Project` wizard. Plus the IDE is built for Android development.

**However**, if you are content with using just plain IntelliJ, then all you have to do is add the reference to the imported **project** - appCompat

Comment: Installed android studio and it worked, don`t know what kind of sorcery it have done but anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, and for anyone else that might see this...if you are doing anything with a **support library** and you are having issues since you are using **Eclipse** or plain **IntelliJ**, then you should simply switch over to **Android Studio** ()